# Token filter for apostrophes in names

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to match queries for "lau", "la'u", and (ideally) "la u" against the following data:

"Laʼu" *(note that's a modified apostrophe)*

My analyzer is:

```
analyzer: {
    folding: { 
        tokenizer: 'icu_tokenizer',
        filter: [ 'lowercase', 'icu_folding_filter' ],
        char_filter: [ 'extended_punctuation_char_filter' ]
    } 
},
char_filter: { 
    extended_punctuation_char_filter: { 
        type: 'mapping',
        mappings: [ '\u02BC => \u0027' ] 
    }
},
...
```

This emits the following token, which shows the modified apostrophe replaced with a plain one:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "la'u",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to also match "lau" and "la u", I assume I need to emit other token permutations. I'm trying to find the token/char filter that allows me to emit multiple tokens representing folded punctuation as above ("la'u"), stripped punctuation ("lau"), and tokens that break on the punctuation itself (i.e. two tokens: "la", "u").

I'm using ES 5.1, but would consider upgrading if there's a solution on 6x.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the synonym token filter. You can replace "lau", "la u" with "la'u".
In SOLR format this would be

```
"synonym": {
        "type": "synonym",
        "format": "solr",
        "synonyms": [
          "lau, l au => la'u"
        ]
      }
```

You can have them all match without replacement as

```
"synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "format": "solr",
            "synonyms": [
              "lau, l au, la'u"
            ]
          }
```

See here for details
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

Comment: That certainly works for the problem as stated, but do you know if there's a way to generalize this for names with apostrophes? I would like any word that includes an apostrophe (i.e. words not reduced by a stemmer upstream) to be tokenized three times: once as-is, once with the apostrophe removed, and once with the apostrophe replaced by a space. Essentially I would like to use the pattern_replace token filter, but have it emit multiple replacements. Some token filters emit multiple tokens, but I don't see any way to make pattern_replace do so.

Comment: @PaulB You can make copy of the field (using "copy_to" mapping) twice and specify different analyzers for each. Check out pattern tokenizer that can tokenize based on user specified pattern

Comment: I must add making copies might not be ideal depending on how big the field that you are analyzing here